# Error in Email Verfier program

Tags: java, email

I have written a Java program to verify email address but this program doesn't work properly.
For example:Whenever we give the input as "1" (excluding double quotes), we get output as "true", but the correct output must be "false".
Please help, as to where am I going wrong.

```
/*This is a java program to verify email address*/

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class EmailVerifyer {

    public boolean isEmail(String email) {
        Pattern p = Pattern
            .compile("^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(email);
        if (!m.matches())
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an email which you would like to verify for correctness: ");
        String email = scanner.nextLine();
        EmailVerifyer emailVerifyer = new EmailVerifyer();
        System.out.println("Output: ");
        System.out.println(emailVerifyer.isEmail(email));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
if(!m.matches())
```

with

```
if(m.matches())
```

Comment: It is but the minimal change to get it working is one character :)

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$");
```

with

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");
```